# ¿Como coloco en esta Función PHP un argumento para que me devuelva un valor del array?

Tags: php, php7

estoy intentando hace ya un rato crear una función con argumento y no resulta como quisiera.

```
function meses(){
$mes = array(
"1" => "Enero", 
"2" => "Febrero", 
"3" => "Marzo", 
"4" => "Abril", 
"5" => "Mayo", 
"6" => "Junio", 
"7" => "Julio", 
"8" => "Agosto", 
"9" => "Septiembre", 
"10" => "Octubre", 
"11" => "Noviembre", 
"12" => "Diciembre");
}
```

La idea es que al llamarla con:

```
meses(); // Aquí iría el argumento/parámetro
```

Resulte seleccionado el valor que se quiera.

Como con: `return $mes[5];`

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 6):

Añade:

- El argumento en la función, que puede estar identificado por cualquier variable entre los paréntesis, en este caso elegí:

Nombre del argumento

```
$posicion
```

- Al ser una función necesitas hacer un `return` del arreglo `$mes` en la posición que se manda como argumento de tu función, con una lectura de este tipo:

Lectura

```
$mes[$posicion];
```

Tu código quedaría:

```
function meses($posicion)
{
    $mes = array(
        "1" => "Enero", 
        "2" => "Febrero", 
        "3" => "Marzo", 
        "4" => "Abril", 
        "5" => "Mayo", 
        "6" => "Junio", 
        "7" => "Julio", 
        "8" => "Agosto", 
        "9" => "Septiembre", 
        "10" => "Octubre", 
        "11" => "Noviembre", 
        "12" => "Diciembre");

        return $mes[$posicion];

}

echo meses(5);
```

Dando como salida:

> Mayo

Obtenemos el resultado anterior, por que tu array es de tipo asoaciativo y estamos haciendo dentro de la función esto: `$mes[5];`, entonces con la variable que le llega a nuestra función lo que le estamos indicando es: del arreglo de meses devuelve aquel cuya clave es 5

Si deseas controlar lo que ocurra si el usuario ingresa un valor fuera de los límites tanto inferior como superior del rango existente *1 - 12* puedes valerte del **Null Coalecense Operator** de este modo en tu función:

```
return $mes[$posicion] ?? "Valor no existente";
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero, dado que vas a utilizar números, te recomendaría que los índices fueran de tipo `entero`, y la respuesta de tipo `string`.

Como mejora a otras opciones, planteo la posibilidad (si utilizas `php7` o superiores) que definas el tipo de parámetro que envías y el tipo de valor que devuelves.

```
function meses(int $posicion): string
{
    $mes = array(
        1 => "Enero", 
        2 => "Febrero", 
        3 => "Marzo", 
        4 => "Abril", 
        5 => "Mayo", 
        6 => "Junio", 
        7 => "Julio", 
        8 => "Agosto", 
        9 => "Septiembre", 
        10 => "Octubre", 
        11 => "Noviembre", 
        12 => "Diciembre");

    if(isset($mes[$position]))
        return $mes[$posicion];

    return "";
}

echo meses(5);
```

Por otra parte, es posible que pongas un valor entero que no existe en tu `array`. Por lo que primero deberías comprobar que existe ese valor, y si no existe, devolver error del tipo que va a devolver la función.

En este caso, tienes el `if` (que comprueba que existe el indice en el `array`) y si no existe, devuelves una cadena vacía.

Answer (score 2):

```
function meses($arg){
    $mes = array(
        "1" => "Enero", 
        "2" => "Febrero", 
        "3" => "Marzo", 
        "4" => "Abril", 
        "5" => "Mayo", 
        "6" => "Junio", 
        "7" => "Julio", 
        "8" => "Agosto", 
        "9" => "Septiembre", 
        "10" => "Octubre", 
        "11" => "Noviembre", 
        "12" => "Diciembre");
        return $mes[$arg];
}
```

Comment: En lugar de poner solo código , si pones un poco de texto aunque la respuesta sea sencilla o obvia tu respuesta queda mucho mejor y mejoraras su calidad! :)

Comment: revisa por favor [answer] tu repuesta debe ser completa y explicar lo que queres hacer con ese codigo.